# Bug or missing thing in my MNIST number recognizer

Tags: c#, .net, math, artificial-intelligence, mnist

2 months ago I started work on my own neural network, I wrote it and it didn't work. Since then I tried a lot of fixes, viewed a lot of videos, guides, and etc. I got how it should work, but didn't figure out what's wrong. I hope you will help me to resolve my dilemma.

Below I placed my calculations and here is project repo within all the code you can run, where I clearly hard coded everything: https://github.com/nick4real/NumberRecognizer

```
// forward prop
[] - 1D array
[,] - 2D array

a0[784] - input layer
a1[16] - hidden layer #1
a2[16] - hidden layer #2
a3[10] - output layer

w1[16,784] - hidden layer #1 weights
w2[16,16] - hidden layer #2 weights
w3[10,16] - output layer weights

b1[16] - hidden layer #1 biases
b2[16] - hidden layer #2 biases
b3[10] - output layer biases

y[10] - expected label

Sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + e^-x)
SigmoidDer(x) = x * (1 - x)

z1[i] = Sum(a0[j] * w1[i,j]) + b1[i]
a1[i] = Sigmoid(z1[i])
z2[i] = Sum(a1[j] * w2[i,j]) + b2[i]
a2[i] = Sigmoid(z2[i])
z3[i] = Sum(a2[j] * w3[i,j]) + b3[i]
a3[i] = Sigmoid(z3[i])
cost[i] = (a3[i] - y[i])^2

// backward prop

alpha - learning rate
(x)` - derivative of x

//output
dcost/da3 = (cost)` = 2 * (a3 - y)
da3/dz3 = SigmoidDer(a3)
dz3/dw3 = (z3)` = a2
dz3/db3 = (z3)` = 1 = da3/dz3
//hidden layer #2
dz3/da2 = (z3)` = w3
da2/dz2 = SigmoidDer(a2)
dz2/dw2 = (z2)` = a2
dz2/db2 = (z2)` = 1 = da2/dz2
//hidden layer #1
dz2/da1 = (z2)` = w2
da1/dz1 = SigmoidDer(a1)
dz1/dw1 = (z1)` = a1
dz1/db1 = (z1)` = 1 = da1/dz1

//update
dcost/dz3 = [10]
dcost/dw3 = [10,16]
dcost/dz3[i] = dcost/da3 * da3/dz3 = 2(a3[i] - y[i]) * SigmoidDer(a3[i])
dcost/dw3[i,j] = dcost/dz3 * dz3/dw3 = dcost/dz3[i] * a2[j]
dcost/db3 = dcost/dz3 * dz3/b3 = dcost/dz3
w3[i,j] = w3[i,j] - alpha * dcost/dw3[i,j]
b3[i] = b3[i] - alpha * dcost/db3[i]

dcost/dz2 = [16]
dcost/dw2 = [16,16]
dcost/dz2[i] = dcost/dz3 * dz3/da2 * da2/dz2 = Sum(dcost/dz3[j] * w3[j,i]) * SigmoidDer(a2[i])
dcost/dw2[i,j] = dcost/dz2 * dz2/dw2 = dcost/dz2[i] * a1[j]
dcost/db2 = dcost/dz2
w2[i,j] = w2[i,j] - alpha * dcost/dw2[i,j]
b2[i] = b2[i] - alpha * dcost/db2[i]

dcost/dz1 = [16]
dcost/dw1 = [16,784]
dcost/dz1[i] = dcost/dz2 * dz2/da1 * da1/dz1 = Sum(dcost/dz2[j] * w2[j,i]) * SigmoidDer(a1[i])
dcost/dw1[i,j] = dcost/dz1 * dz1/dw1 = dcost/dz1[i] * a0[j]
dcost/db1 = dcost/dz1
w1[i,j] = w1[i,j] - alpha * dcost/dw1[i,j]
b1[i] = b1[i] - alpha * dcost/db1[i]
```

Comment: Esper, this is a good effort. Let me give some ideas about how to make progress on a problem like this. Start small -- can you get something working with, say, 2 inputs, no hidden units, and 1 output? Try to get just the forward pass to work. If you have some inputs, no hidden, 1 output, do you get the correct output? Then try some number of hidden units. About training, start small again. Put in some code to debug the gradient calculation by computing finite differences. Do your calculated gradients agree with the finite difference approximation?

Comment: You might try working in Octave or some other package which allows you to do matrix operations -- that can simplify the indexing and looping. Try 1 output unit and just look at recognizing one digit versus all others -- if you can get that to work then expand to all 10 digits. Hope this helps, good luck, and have fun.